# Kill Resque Workers from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, resque

I'm using the following command to start 2 Resque background workers from my CLI.

```
COUNT=2 QUEUE=* rake resque:workers RAILS_ENV=production &
```

When I pull code updates from git to the server, I have to kill the background workers and rerun the command. I typically do something like this:

```
ps -u myuser # this shows me the process I started originally with the ids
kill -9 12345
kill -9 23456
```

Is there a way to kill these background workers from the Resque gem? I would like to create a rake task or a module in Ruby that would allow me to kill and restart these workers.

Comment: What other `rake` tasks are there? `rake -T` can help explain.

Comment: There are only 3: `rake resque:failures:sort`, `rake resque:work`, `rake resque:workers` but none allow me to stop a worker. @tadman

Comment: Not very helpful, then. Normally I deploy this kind of stuff in containers, so management is easier, but you could wrap this up in a `systemd` config to make it as easy as `systemctl start` and `systemctl stop` etc. That makes managing it on a production server a lot easier, especially as now you can check up on the worker status, too, plus log output gets automatically bridged to `journalctl` if your system uses that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `pkill -9 -f resque*` to kill -9 all processes where name matches resque*